# Can the openid-config url, audience, issuer value in the Azure APIM policies be fetched from a different source?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I want to protect the information such as openid-config url, audience, issuer in the azure policies in APIM for JWT validation [Here is the reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS2Kr.png), is there a way to add these details in a more secure way than just adding it in the policy directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [named value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-properties?tabs=azure-portal#use-a-named-value).

Named values are a global collection of name/value pairs in each API Management instance that you can reference in your apim's policies.
Values type can be **plain**, **secret** or even values fetched from **key vault**.